# Exporting a Flutter List to CSV file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this screen which lists the items of a class into ListView. What I would want is to have the button (FloatingActionButton in the code) that would export that list to a CSV file. I have the code of what I think it should look, but my issue is that I don't know how to use onPressed on the button in order to export, for now it is null, but it should call the **getCSV()** function with something in it. Here's the code:

```
  class MailListAdmin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MailListAdminState createState() => _MailListAdminState();
}

class _MailListAdminState extends State<MailListAdmin> {

  List<String> list = [];
  List<Email> finalExport;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseProvider.db.getMail().then(
      (mailList) {
        BlocProvider.of<MailBloc>(context).add(SetMail(mailList));
      },
    );
  }

  getCsv(List<Email> mailList) async {
    List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mailList.length; i++) {
      List<dynamic> row = List();
      row.add(mailList[i].id);
      row.add(mailList[i].email);
      rows.add(row);
      setState(() {
        mailList = finalExport;
      });
      print(rows);
    }
    await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
    bool checkPermission = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(
        Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
    if (checkPermission) {
      String dir =
          (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).absolute.path + "/documents";
      String file = "$dir";
      File f = new File(file + "filename.csv");
      String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
      f.writeAsString(csv);
    }
  }

  //-------------------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        title: Text('Newsletter Users'),
        actions: [
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Badge(
                  child: Text('Copied ' + list.length.toString()),
                  showBadge: false)),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: BlocConsumer<MailBloc, List<Email>>(
          builder: (context, mailList) {
            return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: mailList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Email mail = mailList[index];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: GestureDetector(
                        child: Icon(Icons.copy),
                        onTap: () {
                          FlutterClipboard.copy(mail.email);
                          print('Copied ${mail.email}!');
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                            content: Text(
                              '${mail.email} Copied To Clipboard!',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            ),
                          ));
                          
                          list.add(mail.email);
                          setState(() {
                            list.length.toString();
                          });
                          print(mail.email);
                          print(list);
                        }),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onTap: () {
                      DatabaseProvider.db.deleteMail(mail.id).then((_) {
                        BlocProvider.of<MailBloc>(context).add(
                          DeleteMail(index),
                        );
                      });
                      list.remove(mail.email);
                      print(list);
                      setState(() {
                        list.length.toString();
                      });
                    },
                    title: Text(
                      mail.email,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  Divider(color: Colors.black),
            );
          },
          listener: (BuildContext context, mailList) {},
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Export'),
        onPressed: () =>
            null, //im not sure how to add the mailList to getCsv(???)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check the **export** button, where I am not sure how to activate it with getCSV function. Also, how would I access the saved CSV file after it is saved (where would it be saved in the device?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Create a new list in the class.
2. Assign it to the mail list from the `BlocConsumer`.
3. Then use the list in `onPressed` by passing it to `getCsv` method.

#### The Implementation

`theEmails`  is the new list.

```
class _MailListAdminState extends State<MailListAdmin> {
  List<String> list = [];
  List<Email> finalExport;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseProvider.db.getMail().then(
      (mailList) {
        BlocProvider.of<MailBloc>(context).add(SetMail(mailList));
      },
    );
  }
  
  List<Email> theEmails = [];

  getCsv(List<Email> mailList) async {
    List<List<dynamic>> rows = List<List<dynamic>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mailList.length; i++) {
      List<dynamic> row = List();
      row.add(mailList[i].id);
      row.add(mailList[i].email);
      rows.add(row);
      setState(() {
        mailList = finalExport;
      });
      print(rows);
    }
    await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
    bool checkPermission = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(
        Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
    if (checkPermission) {
      String dir =
          (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).absolute.path + "/documents";
      String file = "$dir";
      File f = new File(file + "filename.csv");
      String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(rows);
      f.writeAsString(csv);
    }
  }

  //-------------------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        title: Text('Newsletter Users'),
        actions: [
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: Badge(
                  child: Text('Copied ' + list.length.toString()),
                  showBadge: false)),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: BlocConsumer<MailBloc, List<Email>>(
          builder: (context, mailList) {
            theEmails = mailList;
            return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: mailList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Email mail = mailList[index];
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: GestureDetector(
                        child: Icon(Icons.copy),
                        onTap: () {
                          FlutterClipboard.copy(mail.email);
                          print('Copied ${mail.email}!');
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[600],
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                            content: Text(
                              '${mail.email} Copied To Clipboard!',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            ),
                          ));

                          list.add(mail.email);
                          setState(() {
                            list.length.toString();
                          });
                          print(mail.email);
                          print(list);
                        }),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onTap: () {
                      DatabaseProvider.db.deleteMail(mail.id).then((_) {
                        BlocProvider.of<MailBloc>(context).add(
                          DeleteMail(index),
                        );
                      });
                      list.remove(mail.email);
                      print(list);
                      setState(() {
                        list.length.toString();
                      });
                    },
                    title: Text(
                      mail.email,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  Divider(color: Colors.black),
            );
          },
          listener: (BuildContext context, mailList) {},
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text('Export'),
        onPressed: (){
          getCsv(theEmails);
        }, //im not sure how to add the mailList to getCsv(???)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate it man, I'm still a bit new to Bloc, so I wasn't sure how to pass it on. Thank you, again!